# VideoView thumbnail does not work on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-videoview

I create videoview in adapter below is my code

```
        VideoThumbnailView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
    }

    public void bind(final int position){
        VideoThumbnailView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mList.get(position).VODUrl));
        VideoThumbnailView.seekTo(100);
```

the code work on android 7 but not work on android 5, has anyone have solution?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it on `Android 5`?

Comment: did you try on real device?

Comment: Yes I try on device Lenovo A 1000, android version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Create video thumbnail using this and set to videoview

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Uri.parse(mList.get(position).VODUrl),
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(thumb);
            VideoThumbnailView.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: I try your code and change videoview to Imageview in xml, but it doesnt't work for me

Comment: sorry late answer,

Comment: I think it didn't work because that's not local path, it's web path:

Comment: value https://homeconnectapp.com/hcm/upload/admin_folder/admin_video/VOD/BlackPanther.mp4